Performance optimal way to serialise Python objects containing large Pandas DataFrames
I am dealing with Python objects containing Pandas DataFrame and Numpy Series objects. These can be large, several millions of rows.
E.g.

@dataclass
class MyWorld:
     # A lot of DataFrames with millions of rows
     samples: pd.DataFrame 
     addresses: pd.DataFrame 
     # etc.

I need to cache these objects, and I am hoping to find an efficient and painless way to serialise them, instead of standard pickle.dump(). Are there any specialised Python serialisers for such objects that would pickle Series data with some efficient codec and compression automatically? Alternatively, I need to hand construct several Parquet files, but that requires a lot of more manual code to deal with this, and I'd rather avoid that if possible.
Performance here may mean

Speed
File size (can be related, as you need to read less from the disk/network)

I am aware of joblib.dump() which does some magic for these kind of objects, but based on the documentation I am not sure if this is relevant anymore.

does pandas not have a built in to_parquet funtion?

there's also polars if it's an option for  you to change, seems faster in general but also I think has a stronger focus on interoperability.

Pandas has to_parquet function and I know how to write individual files. Pleae re-read the question. This is about pickle not writing files.

check out apache arrow (pyarrow) may offer a solution

ah, from the question I had understood that parquet is an alternative for you.. So was thinking it can be streamlined so may not have to be so manual. I have a feeling all solutions with important gains for IO are similar in nature to parquet (feather, arrow, HDF).. So if process is too manual for parquet will be same challenge with these.

perhaps if you could provide more context as too what you are trying to do we can look at solutions on a larger context. In the meantime if you're set on pickle and python you can use if not already the c impl of pickle cpickle and eventually disable garbage collection during the call to serialization, should give some improvement, but idk if side effects, so put some markers to double check if trying

This is the bottom-up pressure that makes all tooling horrendous in data mgmt. There are things like Athena in AWS and delta tables and all sort of other crap that treat files in storage as a single database. Just make a database. you choose how the data is stored

@roganjosh Thank you. As I mentioned in the question, I just want more efficient pickles, with least headache. I do not have time or money to build databases on AWS.

@MikkoOhtamaa Can you give some context? So, are you dealing with marshalling a single object type, multiple types, or saving the state of the entire process? What is efficient - space, runtime, maintenance, or something else?

Let's start with a very large single object, e.g. assume > 100 MB Numpy data but will still fit in RAM, assume disk or network access. Space and run-time are often the same, because for very large objects you read it faster from the disk if it is more efficiently packed.

What about storing huge structures in parquet format while pickling it, this can be automated easily:
import io
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class MyWorld:
    
    array: np.ndarray
    series: pd.Series
    frame: pd.DataFrame

@dataclass
class MyWorldParquet:
    
    array: np.ndarray
    series: pd.Series
    frame: pd.DataFrame
        
    def __getstate__(self):

        for key, value in self.__annotations__.items():
            
            if value is np.ndarray:
                self.__dict__[key] = pd.DataFrame({"_": self.__dict__[key]})
            
            if value is pd.Series:
                self.__dict__[key] = self.__dict__[key].to_frame()
        
            stream = io.BytesIO()
            self.__dict__[key].to_parquet(stream)
            
            self.__dict__[key] = stream
        
        return self.__dict__

    def __setstate__(self, data):
        
        self.__dict__.update(data)
        
        for key, value in self.__annotations__.items():
        
            self.__dict__[key] = pd.read_parquet(self.__dict__[key])
            
            if value is np.ndarray:
                self.__dict__[key] = self.__dict__[key]["_"].values
            
            if value is pd.Series:
                self.__dict__[key] = self.__dict__[key][self.__dict__[key].columns[0]]

Off course we will have some trade off between performance and volumetry as reducing the second requires format translation and compression.
Lets create a toy dataset:
N = 5_000_000
data = {
    "array": np.random.normal(size=N),
    "series": pd.Series(np.random.uniform(size=N), name="w"),
    "frame": pd.DataFrame({
        "c": np.random.choice(["label-1", "label-2", "label-3"], size=N),
        "x": np.random.uniform(size=N),
        "y": np.random.normal(size=N)
    })
}

We can compare the parquet conversion trade off (about 300 ms more):
%timeit -r 10 -n 1 pickle.dumps(MyWorld(**data))
# 1.57 s ± 162 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit -r 10 -n 1 pickle.dumps(MyWorldParquet(**data))
# 1.9 s ± 71.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)

And the volumetry gain (about 40 Mb spared):
len(pickle.dumps(MyWorld(**data))) / 2 ** 20
# 200.28876972198486

len(pickle.dumps(MyWorldParquet(**data))) / 2 ** 20
# 159.13739013671875

Indeed those metrics will strongly depends on the actual dataset to be serialized.

This could help you. Below article describes various ways and one of them is serialization the dataframe.

https://realpython.com/python-serialize-data/#binary-dataframes-parquet

Medium article with serialization benchmarks.

https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-dataframe-serialization-75205b6b7c69

The above articles would give you an idea i.e. how to approach the problem.
Also, can you try converting the dataframe to json using dj.to_json() and then reloading them back as a df?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

While your question is regarding a class including several dataframes. While slightly, off topic, how to efficiently serialize one large dataframe seem relevant. I have used feather here, but parquet should be similar. Assuming we have some large dataframe.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dummy data with 10 million rows
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10**7,100))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[str(i) for i in range(100)])

The feather format is easy to use with pandas. It writes and reads to file quickly and the file size is fairly small. The files can also easily be compressed.
df.to_feather("data.feather")

Compressed with zstd for better performance.
df.to_feather("data.feather", compression="zstd", compression_level=3)

Simple performance comparison
There are two options for compression algorithms "Lz4" and "zstd". As well as several compression levels. I ran a quick performance test, with the dummy data above and compared it to a simple pickle. Each write and read was done 10 times, and the best time is reported.



Compression
Compression level
Write time
Read time
File size




pickle
default
7.57s
3.63s
7.5 GiB


feather
default
4.46s
1.91s
2.5 GiB


zstd
-3
5.73s
2.64s
2.6 GiB


zstd
0
3.38s
1.96s
611.2 MiB


zstd
3
3.28s
1.95s
611.2 MiB


zstd
10
16.60s
1.72s
719.8 MiB


lz4
1
4.24s
1.85s
2.5 GiB


lz4
5
12.73s
1.62s
1.4 GiB


lz4
7
30.55s
1.53s
1.2 GiB



Overall zstd with compression level 3 (which should be the default), seem to be a good balance between write, read and file size. However which option is best depends on where you want to optimize the speed the most. Higher compression seem to lead to faster read times.
Since the optimal compression might depend on the dataframe content I'll include the code I used for running these tests so it's easier to perform your own test.
import timeit
import humanize
import os

# How many times a call inside the timeit.repeat is called
num_experiments = 10
table_time = lambda t: "{:.2f}s".format(t)

def test_compression(compression, compression_level):
    write_t = timeit.repeat('df.to_feather("compressed_data.temp", compression=compression, compression_level=compression_level)', repeat=num_experiments, number=1,
            globals={"df": df, "compression": compression, "compression_level": compression_level})
    write_t = table_time(min(write_t))

    read_t = timeit.repeat('pd.read_feather("compressed_data.temp")', repeat=num_experiments, number=1, globals={"pd": pd})
    read_t = table_time(min(read_t))

    size = humanize.naturalsize(os.path.getsize("compressed_data.temp"), binary=True)

    print(f"{compression} \t\t| {compression_level} \t\t| {write_t} \t| {read_t} \t| {size}")

print("Compression \t| Compr. level \t| Write time \t| Read time \t| File size")
test_compression("zstd", -3)


I was investigating storing large pandas dataframes and after some time the answer is clear:

use polars. It is about 10x faster then pandas for column-like operations and support lazy methods, saving a lot of memory and loadinng time.

the best format is ipc (or feather in pandas) in both saving/loading times and file sizes.


The API to work with it is super easy:
import polars as pl
data = pl.scan_ipc("path_to_file")
# ...some work ...
data.write_ipc("path_to_file")

Plus you can always call data.to_pandas() or data.collect().to_pandas() to return to the pandas API.
